# Download a Macro-Enabled Excel Workbook with PHP

Tags: excel, vba

I want to download a macro-enabled Excel workbook from my PHP page. When the workbook displays, the macro should run. How can I ensure the macro will run after the user opens the Excel workbook?

Comment: Don't understand what you're asking for - could you have a go at rewording the question?

Answer (score 2):

If you call your macro "Auto_Open", Excel will run it when the workbook is opened (subject to user's security settings)